# Calculated Column - with datefield

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have one date column and one calculated Column.
If date column is blank i want to save null in calculated column and if it is provided then calculated column should save that date. 
I tried `=IF(ISBLANK([DateField]),"Null",[DateField])` it works perfect in excel but not in sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Eric,

ISBLANK() is a valid Function and has been since the very start

Here is my tested and tried list of functions:

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

And [here is the MSDN Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/IS-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087) for all Logical Functions

ISBLANK is the correct way for testing for an empty date, so there must be something else wrong.

It can only be with the [DateField]

```
    =ISBLANK([Created])
```

Returns: No

So

```
    =ISBLANK([DateField])
```

Should return Yes or No

You can also try what this returns:

```
=TEXT([DateField],"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Notes:

- on Non-english Locale you might need ; as a separator instead of the ,
- with code you can write any value to a field, there is no checking!
  Has a 'developer' messed with your fields?
- since an empty date field **is** a False value you can use:

  ```
    =IF( [DateField] , [DateField] , "null" )
  ```

*PS. Wrong answers from persons with nearly 30.000 points should be rewarded with a -1000*

Comment: To check..  I recreated a new list and tried.  And it works as expected.  Thanks Danny. I don't understand, why it wasn't working on earlier list.